# Left Column Not 100% Height

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have a green background that should go down the full length of the left column, to just above the footer. I have all respective divs set to 100% height, but it's stopping short.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

div#page-wrap {
  width:960px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

div#body-wrapper {
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

nav#side-navigation {
   height:100%;
   width:185px;
   background-color:#C2F4C2;
   float:left;
}

div#content-wrap {
   width:775px;
   height:100%;
   float:right;
   position:relative;
   background:transparent url(../images/global/column_corner.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Here is the site code: http://freshbaby.com/v20/about_us/index.cfm

Comment: dint c the site thoroughly... but,face a similar problem.. From my experience,u need javascript to achieve this.. else,if u do manage to find a pure CSS solution.. do update me.. :)

Comment: I have done it with pure CSS before, but the more nested DIVs you have the more complex it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this article which did the trick: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 1):

You can use "fake columns", where the backrgound is a vertically tiled background-image in the container element of your columns. (`div#page-wrap`)
As long as your columns are fixed in width, it works nice :)

Read [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) for more details.

Comment: I would not recommend this solution because the issue can be solved by improving/simplifying the markup rather than creating an unnecessary http request and slowing down the site.

Comment: I have done the background image repeat before, but I'm really trying to make this hack-free. And I have done this before with more simple-designed sites.

Comment: Just to see if it would work, placing a repeat-y background graphic in div#page-wrap failed. It seems that this div only extends about 90% of the left column height. South of that, nothing.

Comment: I recall I always had problems with height:100% and stopped using it... If you remove all the 100%-specifications, it will work.

I think whats currently happening is this:
The "90% height", is because that is where your `div#page-wrap` ends. For some reason, your `html` Element ends at this height and all descending 100%-height items (including `#body-wrapper` and `#side-navigation`) inherit this height. The reason the column currently reaches a little further down, is that the position of `#body-wrapper` is moved down by the height of `header`.

Comment: Update: Looks like `html{height:100%;}` sets the height of the element to the height of the viewport.